# Firebase authentication with spring boot not working, only recieves a 401 response

Tags: spring-boot, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a spring boot that uses firebase auth for the project project. the problem is in the login.

```
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) ->
                oauth2ResourceServer
                        .jwt((jwt) ->
                                jwt
                                        .decoder(jwtDecoder())
                        )
            );
```

when i try the localhost:8080/auth/login without a token, it gets me a 401 response but if i put the token in the authorization part in postman, it works.

The login shouldn't need a token to work, thanks in advance

I've tried change , my controller:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    private final LoginService loginService;

    public LoginController(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/auth/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestBody) {
        String email = requestBody.get("email");
        String password = requestBody.get("password");
        String customToken = loginService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Custom token gerado com sucesso: " + customToken);
    }
}
```

my service

```
@Service
public class LoginService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginService.class);

    private static final String FIREBASE_VERIFY_PASSWORD_URL = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword";
    private static final String FIREBASE_API_KEY = "[API KEY HERE]";

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public LoginService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
    String url = FIREBASE_VERIFY_PASSWORD_URL + "?key=" + FIREBASE_API_KEY;
    Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
    requestBody.put("email", email);
    requestBody.put("password", password);
    requestBody.put("returnSecureToken", true);
    logger.debug("Entrando no método signInWithEmailAndPassword");

    try {
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(requestBody),
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

        if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            Map<String, Object> responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();
            if (responseBody != null && responseBody.containsKey("idToken")) {
                return (String) responseBody.get("idToken");
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Falha na autenticação");
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao chamar a API do Firebase Authentication", e);
    }
}
}
```